# divide data with a character from value database

Tags: php

i have a data from database, like this :

```
$data = "abcdefghi";
```

I want to divide the data for each of the 3 characters, and added character newline. I was confused but did count the characters to split. I only know to use modulo `( % 3)`, if i print so like this :

```
abc 
def 
ghi
```

I do not know what syntax should be used. anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = "abcdefghi";
$newData = implode("\n", str_split($data, 3));
var_dump($newData);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split) might be what you need:

```
$data = "abcdefghi";
foreach (str_split($data, 3) as $part)
  echo "$part\n";
```